# Compiler require c++0x but flag already add in the command

Tags: c++11, compilation, g++

The version of compiler is 4.4.6 and it should support c++0x as indicated here: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html

But I still get below compile error:

> ```
> *In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/cinttypes:35,
> ...
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/c++0x_warning.h:31:2:
> error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the
> upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently
> experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
> compiler options.*
> ```

The flag is already added in makefile as below:

```
g++ **-std=c++0x** $(LDFLAGS) $(Objs) -o Test
```

I tried `-std=gnu++0x` but doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show your Makefile ?

Comment: Can you manually invoke the compiler with the command line you think your make system is using and reproduce the issue?

Comment: Issue solved following John's solution. But still thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added the option to your *link* command, not your *compile* command.  You need to add it to CXXFLAGS.